# Select depart date, 5 days from today and return date, 6 days from today in Selenium

Tags: java, datetime, selenium

I am automating a scenario of flight booking on Cleartrip.com(https://www.cleartrip.com/flights) in which I have to enter depart date, 5 days from today and return date, 6 days from today. I have written below code.

```
Date dt = new Date();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(dt);
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);
dt = calendar.getTime();
String departdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").format(dt);

//enter Journy date in the field
WebElement depart = driver.findElement(By.id("DepartDate"));
depart.sendKeys(departdate);

Date dt1 = new Date();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(dt1);
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
dt1 = calendar.getTime();
String returndate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").format(dt1);

//enter returndate in the field
WebElement return= driver.findElement(By.id("ReturnDate"));
return.sendKeys(returndate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the Date type. You can do it all with a Calendar instance and a DateFormat instance:

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(); // gets current date
    now.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);             // add five days
    String firstDate = dateFormat.format(now.getTime());
    ...
    now.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);             // add one more day
    String secondDate = dateFormat.format(now.getTime());
```